# Сохранение настроек

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть программа, в которой есть `админ-панель`.

Если админ захочет, он может изменить название программы, картинки, тексты надписей и пр.

Но те кто будут пользоваться этой программой не могли бы менять её, т.е редактирование ТОЛЬКО через админку.

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было сохранять то, что изменил админ?

Comment: Приложение WinForms или Web?

Comment: Windows Application

Comment: Изменения, внесённые админом, влияют на всех пользователей?

Comment: Ну я не знаю как это объяснить, я сделал прогу с такой картинкой, таким названием, передела другу, он уже изменил название и картинку и сохранил, и если он передаст другим эту прогу, то она уже будет с его названием и картинкой.

Comment: вы нашли решение ?

Answer (score 2):

Стандартные и очень удобные средства для хранения настроек предоставляет обычный механизм `app.config`. Единственная разница в вашем случае *(как я понимаю, вход по `login/password` c шифрованием уже сделан)* заключается в том, что настройки, заданные администратором **необходимо зашифровать** и как-то спрятать от глаз других пользователей.

Первая проблема решается опять же стандартными способами, посмотреть подробнее можно [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535685/best-practices-how-should-i-store-settings-in-c-sharp-format-type) Со второй же все сложнее, т.к стандартные трюки вроде скрытия файла, перемещения его в какую-либо системную директорию и т.п. все равно работают только против не особо умных юзеров.

*Я бы использовал совокупность валидации по чексумме, чтобы отловить возможные сторонние изменения файла, цельное шифрование всего файла каким-либо внутренним ключом и все вышеописанные трюки со скрытием и перемещением.*

---

Если бросаться в крайности, т.е рассматривать ситуации, когда необходима **полная** защита соответствующих данных, то не обойтись без сервера, хранящего настройки, подключения и передачи данных по `SSL`, защите от реверсинга и предупреждения `MITM` атак.

---

Как здесь поступить в итоге, решать, пожалуй, вам.

Comment: Да нет.. просто запихнуть файл в C:\Windows\cmd.txt и все кто туда полезет? Или в текстовом файле нельзя хранить настройки?

Comment: @Angus123 Ну любой человек, слышавший о `filemon`, при желании обнаружит этот файл найдет за 5 минут.

Comment: @Angus123 Можно, конечно, и в текстовом файле, но если за вас уже придумали `app.config`, то зачем изобретать очередной велосипед?

Comment: Да не надо его изобертать, просто надо покопаться в той ссылке что вы скинули. Спасибо если что-то не получится, отпишусь.

Comment: @Angus123 Спасибо, что убедили меня. Действительно, не стоит изобретать велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, просто Вам нужно сделать роли пользователей: админы и обычные пользователи.

Админы обладают правами редактирования.

При авторизации проверяем, обладает ли наш пользователь правами администратора и только тогда (при подверждении обладания роли админа) показываем ему админ-панель.

Comment: Да не форму входа я уже сделал, и саму админ понель, все готово, все меняется, вот только не знаю как сделать чтобы при других запусках все это оставалось, а так уже все готово.